# QGIS Equivalent of MapInfo's 'Combine Objects using Column'

Tags: qgis

MapInfo has a function that takes a table, and creates a new table populated combines them by a specified value.

So, combining on the name field, and specifying that the Area field should be summed...

```
Name                  Area
Ben's Field           100
Ben's Field           50
Tom's Field           25
```

Becomes

```
Name                  Area
Ben's Field           150
Tom's Field           25
```

How can one achieve this in QGIS?

Comment: Are you dissolving (combining) spatial entities (e.g. polygons) or just summarizing a table of data disassociated from any spatial elements?

Comment: Just summarising a table - no spatial elements.